# Automake datadir and prefix in python

Tags: python, autotools, automake

Say I have `my_application.py.in` for automake to generate `my_application.py`. How do I get the datadir into my application with ${prefix} expanded? Right now the best I can figure is to use `replace()` in my python application, but, I'm assuming there is a more appropriate way.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.VERSION = '@VERSION@'
    app.PACKAGE = '@PACKAGE@'
    # How should I get the DATA_DIR in this next line?
    app.DATA_DIR = "@datarootdir@".replace("${prefix}", "@prefix@")
    app.run()
```

Comment: Note: automake does not generate file from .in files: it is the autoconf generated configure script that generates config.status that is used to create the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the substitution at `make` time. This is easier in C, where you can set a `#define`, but for Python, I'd try something like this:

```
foo.py: foo.py.in
        [ -f $@ ] && rm -f $@
        $(SED) -e "s:[@]datarootdir@:$(datarootdir):" $< > $@
        chmod a-w $@
```

(add `AC_PROG_SED` to `configure.ac`)

Comment: Remark: The `[@]` construct is a character class consisting of only `@`. It's done that way to stop `config.status` from grabbing the `sed` pattern when making `Makefile` from `Makefile.in`

Comment: datarootdir is nearly certain to contain '/', so a different delimiter for s is advisable.  This is a good first approximation, but any other substitutions performed by config.status will be missed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Well spotted, thanks. I find myself making a file called `dirs.py` (or `dirs.rb` or similar) that has all the substitutions I care about for that particular project.

Comment: So this would be in Makefile.am? Then I would exclude foo.py from configure.ac to avoid duplciate targets?

Comment: In other words, if I create this rule for the foo.py target in my Makefile.am, I no longer have the default rule as if I had foo.py in AC_CONFIG_FILES, so, none of the other variabels are expanded (package, version etc.). Would I then have to use my own SED replacements for every variable I need to define in foo.py?

Comment: I just got it! Thanks for the help guys. This was useful: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/automake/manual/html_node/Scripts.html

Comment: Good work @Micah. I think you worked this out, but to be explicit: I would no longer list `foo.py` in `AC_CONFIG_FILES`.

Comment: Correct. I'm instead using the rule in Makefile.am so that it is generated at maketime.

Answer (score 0):

One common technique is to use adl_RECURSIVE_EVAL (from the autoconf archive) in configure.ac to produce a fully expanded path.

Comment: Common, perhaps, but I don't think it's correct behaviour. http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Directory-Variables says that these variables should be changeable at `make`-time, which means the expansion should be done at `make`-time.